# rewrite integral so that integrand has no singularity

Tags: integration, singularity

Let $B = \int_{0}^{\pi/4} cos(x)\cdot ln(x)$

rewrite the integral $B$ so that

$B  = a - U $

'where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant and $U = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}g(x)dx$.
The function $g(x)$ has no singularity at $0$ ,that is, it is continuous and bounded around zero.'

...

My solution to the problem is to use partial integration so that

$[sin(x)ln(x)]_{t}^{\pi/4} - \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\dfrac{sin(x)}{x}dx$

Since $lim_{t->0^+}sin(x)\cdot ln(x)=0$ we therefore get  $a = sin(\pi/4)\cdot ln(\pi/4)$.

$g(x) = \dfrac{sin(x)}{x}$ is 'continuous and bounded around zero' however it is not defined at zero. Is it singular at zero? is the textbook being unclear of what they want?  I believe that $\dfrac{sin(x)}{x}$ is singular at zero since it is not defined there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $g(x) = \dfrac{sin(x)}{x}$ can be continuously extended to the same function with $g(0)=1$, which is possible because $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{sin(x)}{x}=1$. Now it's continuous and bounded around $0$.

**Extra babble:**

$U$ here could also be interpreted as an improper Riemann integral without extending the $g$ you found: $U=\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\int_{t}^{\pi/4}g(x)dx$.

For this improper Riemann integral, $g(x)$ doesn't have to be defined in $x=0$, but that's not what the question is asking for.

Comment: yes i know it does not have to be defined ax $x = 0$ but they asked that $g(x)$ should not be singular at zero have I accomplished that @The Phenotype

Comment: Okay, I didn't read your question correctly. Define a new $g$ by the $g$ you found and continuously extend with $g(0)=1$. This is possible, because $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{sin(x)}{x}=1$. This new $g$ is the function you should be looking for. I will now edit my answer accordingly if you don't mind.